# How to get full list of request headers in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I am trying to get a list of all headers sent in a http request in a Micronaut @Controller.

Comment: Do you need them in a list in particular or will any collection do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a variable of type `io.micronaut.http.HttpHeaders` to your API endpoint parameters.  Give this a shot:

```
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Get("/test/http-headers") 
    public HttpResponse<String> getHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders headers) {
        for (val header : headers.entrySet()) {
            // Do stuff with header.getKey() and header.getValue()
        }

        return HttpResponse.ok("Testing");
    }
}
```

Latest docs on `HttpHeaders`: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/HttpHeaders.html#method.summary

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#requestResponse

```
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

@Controller("/request")
public class MessageController {

    @Get("/hello") 
    public HttpResponse<String> hello(HttpHeaders headers) {
        // deal with the headers
        return HttpResponse.ok("Hello world!!")
                 .header("X-My-Header", "Foo"); 
    }
}
```

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/HttpHeaders.html

Comment: I don't think that code sample shows how to get a list of all request headers.  That code sample appears to be setting a response header.

Comment: Jeff look carefully. The headers are injected as method parameter. I assume accessing the header is obvious

Comment: "I assume accessing the header is obvious" - Are you proposing that `headers.iterator()` be invoked to return an iterator that can be interacted with?

Comment: Either that or you use a getAll on headers.. Depends a lot what he want to achieve.

Comment: Right.  I don't think those are necessarily obvious. I think your answer would be more helpful if you included that code.

Comment: Well feel free to add it ;-) thing for me is, that he do not specify what to do with the headers

Comment: "Well feel free to add it" - I don't think it is appropriate for me to add code to your answer.  I expect these comments may be helpful.  If OP still wants clarification I can help.  Thanks for submitting an answer.